# Where to put description of module in documentation?

Tags: discussion

When creating a simple example for a module (at https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/7574/tkinter#t=20161023174956350466), I recieved an improvement request to explain the module's purpose in the example. I added it in using a later edit, but I personally think that the description should probably go in the remarks seciton. Where would be the best place to put this kind of information?